# Is it possible to modify an object passed like a parameter to other thread with C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

As we create sub processes with threads, they are allocated in other space of memory, is it possible or exist any way to change a value from Main Thread to a Worker thread for example?

In this code after five seconds we modify the passed parameter, and it not changes from the Main Thread.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program o = new Program();
        int  year = 2021;

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(o.method));
        thread.Start(year);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(year);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public void method(object p)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        p = 1500;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you go with your custom process/memory management (whatever "create sub processes with threads, they are allocated in other space of memory" it means) C# is probably not a best option... While I think you should go with C++ for code like that you still may want to read on boxing and "value vs. reference types in C#" as both topics apply to general memory mangement.

Comment: Create a new class. Add an `int` property to it. Pass that class around, rather than an `int` directly. Everything will "just work".

Comment: This has nothing to do with threading.  You'll see the same behavior if you just call the method directly with no additional threads.  Parameters are passed by value unless you use ref/out.